# Appending Tuples to an Array of Tuples?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I'm trying to make an array of tuples to store the data of a to-do-list app but can't figure out how to append the tuples to the array. Here is my code:

First, the array was declared globally:

```
var eventList : [(name: String, date: String)] = []
```

Here's the code I tried to use, but I get a complier error saying "Missing argument for parameter 'date' in call". (This line of code is inside a `buttonPressed` action)

```
eventList.append((name: titleField.text, date: convertDate(eventDate.date)))
```

Why is this causing a compiler error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a typealias for your tuple and then use it.

```
typealias MyTuple = (name: String, date: String) 

var eventList : [MyTuple] = []

var v: MyTuple = (name: "A", date: "1")
eventList.append(v)
eventList.append((name: "B", date:"2"))

println(eventList)
```

Comment: Thanks this works (although my convertDate method doesn't print out the date correctly). Is this a work around to a bug in the compiler or just the way arrays of tuples work?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a bug, but the Swift compiler seems to be unhappy about passing anonymous tuples to methods.